# Artificial Neural Network Classifier in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to build a neural network classifier. I have created a neural network with 1 hidden layer (25 neurons) and 1 output layer (1 neuron/binary classification).

The dataset I am using has the following dimensions:

```
size(X_Train): 125973 x 122
size(Y_Train): 125973 x 1
size(X_Test): 22543 x 122
size(Y_test): 22543 x 1
```

My overall goal is to compare different training functions. But, I would like first to get your feedback about my code and how I improve it.

```
% Neural Network Binary-classification

clear ; close all; clc

%% =========== Part 1: Loading Data =============

%% Load Training Data
fprintf('Loading Data ...\n');

load('dataset.mat'); % training data stored in arrays X, y
X_training=X_training';
Y_training=Y_training';
X_testing=X_testing';
Y_testing=Y_testing';

%% Create the neural network
% 1, 2: ONE input, TWO layers (one hidden layer and one output layer)
% [1; 1]: both 1st and 2nd layer have a bias node
% [1; 0]: the input is a source for the 1st layer
% [0 0; 1 0]: the 1st layer is a source for the 2nd layer
% [0 1]: the 2nd layer is a source for your output
net = network(1, 2, [1; 1], [1; 0], [0 0; 1 0], [0 1]);
net.inputs{1}.size = 122; % input size
net.layers{1}.size = 25; % hidden layer size
net.layers{2}.size = 1; % output layer size

%% Transfer function in layers
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'logsig';

net.layers{1}.initFcn = 'initnw';
net.layers{2}.initFcn = 'initnw';

net=init(net);

%% divide data into training and test
net.divideFcn= 'dividerand';
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 60/100; % 80% training
net.divideParam.valRatio = 20/100; % 20% validation set
net.divideParam.testRatio = 20/100; % 20% validation set

net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';

%% Training functions
net.trainFcn = 'trainscg'; %Scaled conjugate gradient backpropagation

%% Train the neural network
[net,tr] = train(net,X_training,Y_training); % return the network and training record

%% Test the Neural Network on the training set
outputs = net(X_training);
errors = gsubtract(Y_training,outputs);
performance = perform(net,Y_training,outputs);

%% Plots  (%training)
figure, plotperform(tr)
figure, plottrainstate(tr)

%% Test the Neural Network on the testing test
outputs1 = net(X_testing);
errors1 = gsubtract(Y_testing,outputs1);
performance1 = perform(net,Y_testing,outputs1);

figure, plotconfusion(Y_testing,outputs1)
figure, ploterrhist(errors1)
```

Below if the validation curve.

[image]

Confusion Matrix (Training set)

[image]

Confusion Matrix (Testing set)
[image]

Any remarks?

**Edit:**

I have used feature scaling or normalization:

```
net.performParam.normalization = 'standard';
```

which has improved the overall accuracy: [image]

For more information, I have added the error histogram:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a code reviewer, but I'd like to comment on the design of your network, which you certainly seem to be doing just fine.

- It might be rather difficult to make any judgment, given that the application is undefined, while it seems you are designing a neural-network based detector.
- Numerically speaking, you might focus on your validation performance, by constantly redesigning your *network architecture* (e.g., number of hidden layers, number of hidden neurons, reducing and increasing batch sizes, training functions/methods as you mentioned, etc.), *input preprocessing* (e.g., smoothing, input interpolation or extrapolation in case possible, artifact removal, etc.).
- Not knowing what your datasets might be and how sophisticated that may be, you may focus on `10^-3` to `10^-6` convergence range. It might increase the performance (e.g., confusion matrices) of your network.

Overall, it seems your input is pretty stochastic. Input preprocessing may be worth looking into.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Can you tell me what made you say the input is stochastic ? I have used all the features, and my dataset contains a lot of one-hot encoded features.